# I need to stop my walk animation once my character has reached the destination

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Problem statement :How can I apply a Stop on my Animation when my character moves and reaches destination.

I have the destination as a float but I am not sure how to incorporate the stop animation.

I thought about a threshold variable in X but just adding another IF statement does not stop my animation.

unitAnimator.SetBool("IsWalking", false);

```
       private void Update()
      {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            MoveToCursor();

        }
      }

      private void MoveToCursor()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); 
        RaycastHit hit;
        bool hasHit = Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);
        var hitPoint = hit.point;
        hitPoint.z = 0;
        float x = 0.3f;
        var playerPosition = transform.position;
        playerPosition.z = 0;
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(hitPoint,playerPosition);
   
        Debug.Log($"Distance: {distance}", this);

        if(hasHit)
        {
            GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().destination = hit.point;
            unitAnimator.SetBool("IsWalking", true);
             

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can change the transition duration time from your walking animation to your stopping or idle animation in your animator to 0 and uncheck the "Has Exit Time" tickbox

Answer (score 0):

I can't see you using this X variable anywhere, do you mean that you tried, it didn't work and you removed the check?

One way to adress this problem is to measure distance between destination and the player position and check if it is bigger than the treshold:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        MoveToCursor();
    }

    if(Vector3.Distance(destination, transform.position) < offset)
    {
        unitAnimator.SetBool("IsWalking", false);
    }
}

Vector3 destination;
float offset = 0.3f;

private void MoveToCursor()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    bool hasHit = Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);
    var hitPoint = hit.point;
    hitPoint.z = 0;
    var playerPosition = transform.position;
    playerPosition.z = 0;
    var distance = Vector3.Distance(hitPoint, playerPosition);

    Debug.Log($"Distance: {distance}", this);

    if (hasHit)
    {
        destination = hit.point;

        GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().destination = hit.point;
        unitAnimator.SetBool("IsWalking", true);

    }
}
```

I'm not sure if doing it in update is the very best solution, but there you go. You could also use `NavMeshAgent` properties for this to be more precise and/or look more elegant. Link for reference: https://answers.unity.com/questions/324589/how-can-i-tell-when-a-navmesh-has-reached-its-dest.html

Comment: Yes. I tried X and removed it because I could not make it work. 


Thank you. I will look into the Navmesh thing aswell